# Loop over nested list

Tags: python, opencv

I want to find the minimum distance between each close center point that I detected. for that, I found all the distance between each detected object with others and listed it on a list like this:

```
mylist = [[0, 1, 23.0],[0, 2, 26.0], [0, 3, 30.0], [1, 2, 25.0], [1, 3, 31.0],[2, 0, 26.2], [2, 1, 25], [2, 3, 28]]
```

where the two first elements are the name of points and the third is the distance between these two points.
my question is that how to find the min distance between each two-points and added to the separate list for instance

```
min = [[0, 1, 17.0],[1, 2, 19.0],[2, 3, 12.0]]
```

Here is my sample code

```
min1 = float('inf')
points = []

i=0 
for elem in mylists:
    # elem[0] shows the first elemnt in the list which is a first point
    if elem[0] == i and elem[2] < min1:  
       # print(elem)
        min1 = elem[2]

        points.append([elem[0], elem[1], min1])
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

i'd try this:

```
A = [[1,2,3.5],[1,2,5],[1,2,2],[1,2,8],[1,2,12]]
min([A[i][2] for i in range(len(A))])
```

Comment: I tried this code but it only shows one min. I want to get the min value for each point: mylist[[1,2, 25.0], [1,3, 29.0],[2, 3, 25.0],[2,4, 34.0]]  as you can see the first index changes. i want to get min value for index 1,2, 3, ..!

Comment: I get it. try having a redundent myList with 2 times each distance. like so [[1,2, 25],[2,1, 25]] then pick every list starting with 1 and minimize then pick every list starting with 2 and minimize.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
distances_local = {}
for dist in mydists:
    closest_window, min_distance = distances_local.get(dist[0], (None, None))
    #print(closest_window, min_distance)
    if min_distance is None or dist[2] < min_distance:
        distances_local[dist[0]] = (dist[1], dist[2])

result = list(map(lambda kv: (kv[0], kv[1][0], kv[1][1]), distances_local.items()))
print(distances_local)
print(result)
```